# Getting error Basemap Layers cannot be published directly to service

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, map-service, arcgis-online-basemaps

I am trying to take a map from a PDF document and get it so I can use it in ArcGIS Online. I was following a great tutorial but ran into a snag.

My overall methodology is to georeference the pdf map (that I converted into a JPG before putting it into ArcMap Desktop) and then I get it the way I want it. After I georeference the JPG image I rectify and delete the base map I was using. Now I go to share as a service ---> publish a service --> choose a connection ---> and then I fill out the service editor. However, once I click analyze I get this error:

```
Severity: High    
Status: Unresolved    
Code: 00037    
Description: Basemap Layers cannot be published directly to a service    
Name: Basemap    
Type: Payer    
Data Frame: Layers
```

I don't know why I am getting this error! I uploaded an image so you can see my screen.

Any advice?

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please vote it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All layers in your project are published in the service, including the Esri basemaps in your table of contents. Please remove ALL layers and tables from your table of contents prior to publishing. see screenshot below of Esri standard basemaps (in ArcGIS Pro)

[image: screenshot of basemaps]

You should be able to highlight the problem layer in the "Prepare" window, then right-click -> remove.

[image]